# WebApi - Convert null string into null value

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api2

What is the best way to convert a 'null' string (passed into a url) to a null value in WebApi using attribute routing?

Url sample:

> localhost:29365/api/myController/Test/first/null/third

Api Controller Method sample:

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("~/api/MyController/Test/{first}/{second}/{third}")]
public void Test(string first, string second, string third)
{ ... }
```

Comment: you want null value as "null" in your parameter

Answer (score 0):

Well your only option would be comparing if the string value is null. However this seems terrible.

Why not try passing as parameters instead.

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("~/api/MyController/Test")]
public void Test(string first = null, string second = null, string third = null)
{ ... }
```

URL Sample

> localhost:29365/api/myController/Test?first=myfirstvalue&third=mythirdvalue

By not supplying the second value it is null by default.

Comment: I've thought about that, but requests are sent with 'null' string inside and unfortunately I cannot change the way it works.

Comment: If you dont have any control over the source of the URL then you dont have a choice. You need to just do a simple string comparisson.